# Change SQLITE LIMIT COMPOUND SELECT

Tags: iphone, sqlite

How to change the SQLITE_LIMIT_COMPOUND_SELECT at run time. I need to know how to use that statement

```
int sqlite3_limit(sqlite3*, int id, int newVal);
```

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/limit.html) seems pretty clear to me. What have you tried, and what happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

I see you're question is tagged iPhone even though there isn't any mention in your question. In Objective-C this is how you can do it:

```
#import <sqlite3.h>

...

NSString *pathToDatabase = @"Path to database file";
NSInteger limitAmount = 10; // or whatever number you want
sqlite3 *database;
if(sqlite3_open([pathToDatabase UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK)
{
   NSLog(@"Unable to connect to the database...");
}
sqlite3_limit(database, SQLITE_LIMIT_COMPOUND_SELECT, limitAmount);
```